# JavaScript Alert if sentences does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, alert

I would like to check if the value in input would not include anything except "o" "x" "",and if it includes want to pop up alert. For now, the problem is that it would pop up alert even though I put "o" "x". I would appreciate your help! Here is my code

```js
var block=document.getElementById("block");
block.change = check;
    function check(){
 if(block.value !== "○" || block.value !== "×" || block.value !== ""){ 
        window.alert('input o or x'); 
  return false; 
 }
 else{
  return true; 
 }
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="block%s" id="block" onchange="check()">
```

Comment: are these the normal `o` and `x` characters? What if someone enters `oxo`?

Comment: Also, 'not equal to "o" OR not equal to "x"' evaluates to true 100% of the time.

Comment: if the value is 'o' then it's not going to be 'x'... you need to use login and instead of or.

Comment: Search for `javascript != or !==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should be:

```
function check(){
    if(block.value !== "○" && block.value !== "×" && block.value !== ""){ 
        window.alert('input o or x'); 
        return false; 
    }
    else{
        return true; 
    }
}
```

You need to use and (&&) condition

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Your code:
/*var block=document.getElementById("block");
function check(){
if(block.value !== "○" || block.value !== "×" || block.value !== ""){ 
    window.alert('input o or x'); 
    return false; 
}
else{
    return true; 
}*/

// Corrected code:
function check() {
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  
  switch(block.value) {
    case 'o':
    case 'x':
    case '':
      break;
    default:
      window.alert('input o or x');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="block%s" id="block" onchange="check()">
```

Comment: 3s instead of Es, very edgy.. plus one